# What should be emphasized - description or the hyper link?

Tags: hyperlinks, font, font-sizes

Signature which I have on other fora:

> Interested in Drawing, Painting, and Crafts?
>   Please Commit to the [Arts and Crafts Stackoverflow proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts).

All the font is Impact.
The words "Drawing, Painting, and Crafts" are bold and have the font size 3, and remaining words have font size 2 including the hyperlink.

Here is a photo of what it looks like:

[image]

What should be emphasized - description or the hyper link?

Comment: This should move to [GraphicDesign.SE].

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the location of the signature is in what I sometimes call the 'suicide slot' - bottom right of most pages is an area people ignore (based on eye tracking heatmaps). It's partly an aesthetic judgement, but there's too much going on visually here for me. I would consider making everything in the same style apart from the link - the link will stand out more anyway because of the styling and it's the thing you want people to click on. There is duplication of the word 'crafts', so the only additional value you're getting with the precursor copy is expanding 'arts' into 'drawing and painting'. So I would change to 'Please commit to my Arts and Crafts Stackoverflow proposal' (note the lower-case 'c' on commit - no need for this to be upper case) and position it on the left.

Comment: There is a lot of empty space on the left side of the signature. Why doesn't that, according to you, work as negative space to draw attention to the signature?

Comment: All IMO of course - I'm not a graphic designer so use of negative space isn't something I'm an expert on. I'm going from eyetracking work such as https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eye+tracking+heat+map&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=978&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIh9Kzz8qCxwIVwjsUCh35DwSf which shows the bottom right isn't a great place when most of the content is left aligned.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius From John Kane's *A Type Primer*, in defining grid fields: "it's useful to remember that the upper left corner of any field is considered the strong or 'active' corner.' The lower right corner is considered the weak or 'passive' corner."

Answer (score 3):

My suggestions:

1. Do what Peter said (make all styling the same apart from link)
2. Reword the link to focus on the value to the customer, or what they will accomplish, rather than focusing on what you want them to do.

Just as a quick example (link is shown in bold text):

"Commit to our StackExchange proposal, and **help us establish an Arts & Crafts community**"

Comment: Great example of a better way to word this and present the link. The link text here, will draw the eye and works well on its own (provides a level of understanding), the preceding text then helps to give more context if the user hasn't already read it.

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing is emphasizing what is most important. I'm assuming that in this case it is the hyperlink.

Make sure everything has the same styling, that way the hyperlink will stand out more. What you should also do is make people want to click it. Give it some provocative copy writing such as "*...help us by committing..*" or something of that nature.

Also, as mentioned before, the bottom-right might not be the best place to put this information, based on eyetracing heatmaps (even though there is a lot of negative space around it).

Answer (score 0):

Generally emphasized should be the core parts of description instead of only description. Why? Because you want to attract user's attention with emphasizing only description there is no difference between other part of content, emphasizing the hyperlink this is not a good idea. Emphasizing is for distinguish the core part of content.

However for forum the great idea should be emphasized the description. Why? Because then visitors can do skim reading to faster skip not interesting posts from their side and see where a post starts and ends.

What is a description? "IMO...salt" or "Interested in Drawing, Painting, and Crafts?"